# Why does this simple_form find the wrong record for an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a `Node` object I am trying to update in a modal.

This is the simple_form in the modal that is butchering the object:

```
# shared/_tag_icon.html.erb

<%= simple_form_for node, url: add_tagged_user_node_path(node), method: :post do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :user, label: "Users", collection: @users, as: :check_boxes, checked: node.user_tags %>
  </div>                            

  <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is rendered from the `shared/_box.html.erb` partial:

```
<%= render partial: "shared/tag_icon", locals: { node: node } %>
```

Which itself is being rendered within a loop on the `Dashboard#Index` view:

```
<% @nodes.each do |node| %>
  <div class="box">
     <%= render partial: "shared/box", locals: {node: node} %>
  </div>
<% end %> <!-- node -->
```

This is a truncated version of my `Dashboard#Index` controller action:

```
  def index
    @nodes = @family_tree.nodes.includes([:comments => :user], :media, :node_comments, :user, :user_tags)
    tagged_nodes = Node.tagged_with(current_user.email)    

    if !tagged_nodes.empty?
      tags = tagged_nodes.collect do |node|
        node.user_tags
      end
      tags.flatten!

      @tagged_users = tags.collect do |tag|
        User.find_by email: tag.name
      end
      @tagged_users.reject!(&:blank?)
    end        
  end
```

I don't think any of the latter part of that controller was relevant, but given that it did interact with some `node` objects, I included it just to be safe.

The issue I am having is that no matter which node I try to tag (i.e. execute that modal/simple_form on), it always produces the latest node - i.e. the most recently uploaded node, and not the node that was passed in via the partials).

I added debugging statements along the way, and when the video renders on the `Dashboard/Index` it does so properly. It is just once it hits that simple_form, everything goes awry.

**Edit 1**

I even tried moving the original rendering of `shared/_tag_icon` partial to the `Dashboard#Index` view and I am still getting the wrong value in that modal on that node.

Comment: Have you looked at that POST request log for the params sent through the form? And I believe the problem is in the `create` action that the form is sent to.

Comment: Yeh the params for the POST request show the ID of the wrong node (i.e. the newest node). But what I am saying is that even before the form sends the POST request (i.e. while the modal is displayed on the screen, so no server log is created, just a modal display) it shows the wrong ID for the node within that modal. I added some basic debugging statements and it printed the wrong ID for the node in that modal.